# Hide text after input

Tags: html, css

How can I hide `Some text` with this html structure?

I am trying without success this:

```
input, .checkbox label > input::after{
    display: none;
}

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="post_yes_no" name="post_yes_no" type="checkbox">Some text
    <small><small><br>*Some info</small></small>
</label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ex26btqd/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no css selector for text nodes
you must wrap it with a `p` or a `span` so you can style it
or you can try use `visibility` instead of `display`

```
label{
visibility: hidden;

}

label input, label small {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Nice! `visibility` is definitely the way to go here. Don't know why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

`input::after` targets the `::after` pseudo-element, not anything that comes after the input.

If you need to hide it with just CSS you can try the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/ex26btqd/5/

This will not truly hide the content -- it is there, but with a transparent color.

If you need to target the text with css, it's much better to wrap it in an element like `<span>` so that it can be targeted by css. Text Nodes cannot be targeted, only elements.

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-target-only-the-stray-text-inside-a-div/#post-202467